# Azimuth greater than 360 in Veloview (Velodyne 32)?

Tags: lidar, azimuth, veloview

When I use Veloview, freezes at 1 of the frames and examine the data points, why are the azimuths greater than 360 degrees?

[image]

Comment: Technically, azimuth is continuous, and not limited to range [0,360) or [-180,180) degrees (or [0,2pi) or [-pi,pi), but I doubt these values are in degrees, and it's not obvious how this pertains to GIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the HDL-32E manual, the rotational angle is given by a two byte integer value ranging between 0 and 35999.  Dividing that value by 100 gives you the degrees. What you see in the azimuth column is the raw integer value returned.

For example the first row entry would have an azimuth value of 143.89°.